# How to understand "than was possible by either phone or mail"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

> College professors were depending on ARPAnet to send messages to each
> other, and share information faster and more economically **than was
> possible by either phone or mail**.

Can i rewrite the phrase to

> "College professors were depending on ARPAnet to send messages to each other, and share information faster and more economically than **(it)** was possible **(to economically  share messages)** by either phone or mail." ?

Is the original usage common? It is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* say 'than it was possible to do by either phone or mail'. However, the condensed version is perfectly normal in formal English.

Comment: Which parts of speech is "than" in the condensed version, pronoun or conjunction?

Comment: _Than_ is never a pronoun. The dictionary says that it's either a conjunction or a preposition; the distinction isn't very clear, but I'd say it's a conjunction here.